# How to quickly query/verify if a pod is "bare pod" or a pod supported by replication controller?

Tags: kubernetes

In OKD v3.11, how to find out if pods running on a node are under the control of replication controller. Is there an oc command or console feature that quickly find the information? Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can relly on the `ownerReferences` API object to find this:

> $ kubectl explain pod.metadata.ownerReferences
>
> KIND:     Pod
>
> VERSION: v1
>
> RESOURCE: ownerReferences <[]Object>
>
> DESCRIPTION:
>        List of objects depended by this object. If ALL objects in the list have
>        been deleted, this object will be garbage collected. If this object is
>        managed by a controller, then an entry in this list will point to this
>        controller, with the controller field set to true. There cannot be more
>        than one managing controller.

Bare pods (i.e., pods without controllers/owners) will not contain the `ownerReferences` field, so you can use the `--custom-columns` to find out which pods are controlled or not:

```
$ kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o custom-columns=NAME:.metadata.name,CONTROLLER:.metadata.ownerReferences[].kind,NAMESPACE:.metadata.namespace
NAME                               CONTROLLER   NAMESPACE
nginx-85ff79dd56-tvpts             ReplicaSet   default
static-pod1                        <none>       default
static-pod2                        <none>       default
coredns-5644d7b6d9-6hg82           ReplicaSet   kube-system
coredns-5644d7b6d9-wtph7           ReplicaSet   kube-system
etcd-minikube                      <none>       kube-system
kube-addon-manager-minikube        <none>       kube-system
kube-apiserver-minikube            <none>       kube-system
kube-controller-manager-minikube   <none>       kube-system
kube-proxy-fff5c                   DaemonSet    kube-system
kube-scheduler-minikube            <none>       kube-system
storage-provisioner                <none>       kube-system
tiller-deploy-55c9c4b4df-hgzwm     ReplicaSet   kube-system
```